# Hiding complex microdata structures

Tags: semantic-web, semantic-markup, microdata

To embed microdata that should be hidden or isn't provided as text you can use `meta` elements. Here is an [example for non-visible properties using meta elements](http://schema.org/docs/gs.html#advanced_missing). Is there a similar way to hide instances of types?

For example I have a page with a table that lists events of a single performer. The performer is implicit and is not repeatedly shown for every entry, so I hide it in a `meta` element. The [performer property](http://schema.org/MusicEvent) should be of the type [Person](http://schema.org/Person), which has additional attributes that I also want to hide. I'm trying to achieve something like this:

```
<meta itemprop="performer" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
    <meta itemprop="name" content="Some performer"/>
</meta >
```

Of course this won't work, the [meta element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.4.4.2) must be empty. Using other elements and hiding them with CSS would work but probably isn't very nice for screen readers. Is there any recommended way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the person scope could be a `<span>` tag? That tag has no semantic value and if there are only meta tags inside it, it shouldn't be visible in your site.

You could also look into itemref and add the Person only once to the page and reference that id multiple times. However not all testing tools support itemref, so testing if it's correctly set up is quite hard at the moment.